# Yii Framework vs Struts2

Tags: java, php, yii, struts2, struts

I am raising this discussion make us understand the differences and similarities of MVC frameworks.

I have used Struts2 framework before but i have not done any acces controlling with Struts, 
Recently i started using Yii Framework and i see Role base access control can be easily integrated in to our web applications using the features provided by Yii Framework. So i would like to know , does Struts2 also provide a machanisum to integrate Role based access control in to our web application with out having to develop it by our selfs.

Also , implementing Authentication system with Yii is quite easy. So how can we compare this with what is provided by Struts2.

Your comments on this post is highly appreciated.

Thank You in advance

Comment: Yii is a PHP framework. Struts2 is a Java framework. I don't see how this could be a useful comparison.

Comment: I am not comparing based on language. of course yii is php and Struts2 is JAVA, i am comparing the frameworks by features they are offering

Comment: Say for an example how much effort we have to put to get the same authentication functionality done using Struts2 framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not any idea about Yii but its not always good way to compare two frameworks.When we talk about comparison first point of difference is the platform they have been implemented.

- Its quite difficult to give an inputs based on this criteria.Me being java inclined will always go for java based platform as my first choice as it will give me an edge to start things more quickly might be some one else have PHP base will go for Yii.
- Without any requirement its not possible to do any comparative study between any platforms and its always quite possible that for some set of requirements one framework will be the best choice and while for some-others it is not a best choice.So in end its always the requirements which decides what is best for you not the features of any platform.

IMHO Role based model/ authentication system is not a part of any MCV platform and even in struts2 it provides you all flexibility to integrate any of the existing system such as Spring security.

And such features (Authenticate system) is only specific to some requirements and not a part of a standard MVC platform.So the developer of Yii might have decided that they want to give that added features while Struts2 team decided to provide extensions so that developer can integrate any system as per there choice, that is purely a design decision.